# date in 117/12/31 format

Tags: r, date

I have dates where 117/12/31 means 17/12/31. How can I extract the year 17 and paste 20 to it and change it to year 2017? For dates before 2000, the format is (e.g.) 89/12/31. In this case I need to get the year format as 1989.

Answer (score 5):

Using the POSIXlt format, you can just add 1900 to the year, as it stores the parts of the date separately.

```
df  <- c("117/12/01", "102/04/01", "89/12/31")
foo <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(df, tz="UTC"))
foo$year <- foo$year + 1900
as.Date(foo)
## [1] "2017-12-01" "2002-04-01" "1989-12-31"
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying splitting on the `/`, adding 1900 to the year part, then recombining and parsing.

```
x <- c("117/12/31", "89/12/31")
```

#### Step 1: Split on `/`

```
library(stringr)
parts <- str_split_fixed(x, "/", 3)
mode(parts) <- "integer"
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  117   12   31
## [2,]   89   12   31
```

#### Add 1900

```
parts[, 1] <- parts[, 1] + 1900
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 2017   12   31
## [2,] 1989   12   31
```

#### Recombine

```
recombined <- apply(parts, 1, paste, collapse = "-")
## [1] "2017-12-31" "1989-12-31"
```

#### Parse

```
as.Date(recombined)
## [1] "2017-12-31" "1989-12-31"
```

Comment: would it work for dates in the previous century, i.e. 12 Dec 1890 = -10/12/12 ?  :-)

Comment: @BenBolker Yes. I think also BCE dates, but I can never remember what is supposed to happen with going from 1BCE to 1CE.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an even easier solution.

```
 df  <- c("117/12/01", "102/04/01", "89/12/31")
```

Count the number of characters in your string and then remove the first one if the length of the string is greater than 8.

```
df <- ifelse(nchar(df)>=9, stringr::str_sub(df, -8), df)

df_dates <- as.Date(df, "%y/%m/%d")

df_dates
#[1] "2017-12-01" "2002-04-01" "1989-12-31"
```

Comment: The is problematic if there are dates from 1968 or before. For example `68/01/01` and  `168/01/01` would both be considered to be 1968 Jan 1st. If the dataset is restricted to only recent dates, this is OK.

Comment: BTW, the easiest way to get the last 8 characters of a string is `stringr::str_sub(x, -8)` or `stringi::stri_sub(x, -8)`.

Comment: if answer wants to stay completely with base R then `dplyr::if_else` could easily be changed to `ifelse` ...

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
x <- c("117/12/31", "89/12/31")
m <- gregexpr('^1?(?=\\d{2})', x, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(x, m) <- c('19', '20')[nchar(x) - 7]
as.Date(x, '%Y/%m/%d')

# [1] "2017-12-31" "1989-12-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `regular expressions` with no loops and even avoid the `*apply` family:

```
x <- c("117/12/01", "102/04/01", "89/12/31")
m <- regexpr("\\d{2,3}",x)#Find the positions and even the values

regmatches(x,f) <- as.numeric(regmatches(x,m)) + 1900 #REPLACE THE VALUES
x
[1] "2017/12/01" "2002/04/01" "1989/12/31"
```